# Is Comp comparator used in STL required to never change compared objects in STL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, language-lawyer

I was examining old deprecated code that used `std::auto_ptr` and I was wondering if this is an undefined behaviour:

```
std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int>> v;
//populate v with elements...

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto a, auto b) {/* some reasonable "less" comparison */});
```

Now, this kind of comparator of course empties the collection, because copy constructor of `std::auto_ptr` takes non-const reference. I was looking for a rule in standard that mandates such behaviour, but all I was able to find is this:

> **[alg.sorting#2]** Compare is a function object type.
>   The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool, yields true if the first argument of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise.
>   Compare comp is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation.
>   **It is assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.**

But this is at least not enough, because comparator that takes two std::auto_ptr by value does not "apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator" - copy constructor is not applied by comparator itself.
Moreover, very same issue applies to superclass of `Compare` - in [algorithms.requirements#7] paragraph about `BinaryPredicate` we can read almost the same sentence:

> binary_­pred shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterators.

Which means, if issue exists, will be propagated to many other algorithms.

My question is: Is comparator, that takes `std::auto_ptr` arguments by value, violates requirements for `std::sort` making call to it an undefined behaviour, or this code is fine, just works wrong ; )? Or, maybe this is an issue in C++ Standard Library specification?

Read more:

- http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#2.sentence-4
- http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#7.sentence-4
- http://www.eel.is/c++draft/sort
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

Comment: Related: https://wg21.link/LWG3031

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically [LWG 3031](https://wg21.link/LWG3031).

Your comparison object doesn't violate any of the stated preconditions of how `Compare` should behave, which is a standard defect. You're not invoking any non-`const` operations on the objects, you're invoking a non-`const` copy constructor. That isn't really covered.

---

However, this particular example *is* undefined behavior for a different reason: your comparison, due to its destroying all of its elements, will fail to be a strict weak order - which runs afoul of [[algo.sorting]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#3.sentence-3).

Comment: I'm not fully convinced: such comparator, if "reasonable", still works. Of course, it modifies underlined collection, but for given two auto_ptr values returns what specification requires.

Comment: @MichałŁoś Can you give an example of a "reasonable" comparator that is more complex than `return false;`?

Comment: Actually - the one you've described is reasonable enough : D, but here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ace61f082d999a0a - note that I pointed out values passed to comparison rather than object identities.

Comment: @MichałŁoś I don't know that you can call that a valid strict weak order though. Cause if you had `auto_ptr<int> a(new int(1)), b(new int(2)), c(new int(3));` you'd have `compare(a,b)` and `compare(b,c)` (with `b` now empty), but then `!compare(a,c)`.

Comment: I fully agree with that, but isn't the intent of notation used in standard to treat "a" and "b" values rather than actual objects? For example: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#4.1. That's how at least I understood that.

Comment: @MichałŁoś Very hard to definitively state how `a` and `b` should be treated when `a` and `b` aren't even defined :)