# Why can't I use a non-const parameter function with stable_sort()?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool foo(string&s1, string&s2);

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    istringstream istrm("counts elements for which predicate p returns");
    vector<string> vec;
    string word;
    while (istrm >> word) {
        vec.push_back(word);
    }

    stable_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), foo); //Conversion Error
    //sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), foo); //Using sort is also OK.

    //Below is OK.
    //int size_num = 7;
    //auto num = count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [size_num](string &s1) {
    //  return s1.size() > size_num;
    //});
    //cout << num;
} 

bool foo(string&s1, string&s2) {
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}
```

I got a conversion error while passing a non-const parameter function to `stable_sort`, but `count_if` is fine.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), it seems that using a non-const parameter function is totally fine.

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>    `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`
>   The signature does not need to have **const &**, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: So what type of objects do functions in `algorithm` pass to a predicate? Only `const`? Only `non-const`? Or could it be both?

Comment: The cppreference page means that you can omit `const &`  (NOT replace it with `&` as you have done)

Comment: This looks like a standard library bug to me.

Comment: @M.M But why does `std::sort` works and `std::stable_sort` does not?

Comment: @M.M [alg.sorting] only mentions using dereferenced iterators as arguments. (That the algorithms require MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable implies other objects are also valid, but I'd take the dereferenced iterator usage as the only requirement on valid comparator parameter types, since nothing says the comparator must take an rvalue.)

Comment: @M.M So my understanding from cppreference is correct?

Comment: I interpret "the signature does not need to have `const &`" as saying that you could either have it or not have it;  it's not condoning the third alternative of `&`

Comment: @M.M Ok, I see. Thanks for your clarification. So easy to misunderstand... So some algorithms' predicate with `&`  could work are totally wrong codes. :D

Comment: @Rick well the standard is unclear, it's too early to say the code is right or wrong. We await clarification from LWG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently a defect in the Standard, see [LWG 3031](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3031).

The existing major implementations don't work with such a comparator in some cases and the Standard is unclear about whether it is supposed to work or not.

Similar question: [Is Comp comparator used in STL required to never change compared objects in STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705889/is-comp-comparator-used-in-stl-required-to-never-change-compared-objects-in-stl)

Comment: Aha! Cool. May I ask a small out of topic question here? I wonder how did you find that **Defect Report** so quickly? Simply using Google could work? Btw, I suggest   deleting the first comment below the question. Since my understanding is correct, right? :D Thanks anyway.(O^~^O)

Comment: I searched stackoverflow for keywords on this topic and found that other question linked in my answer, which itself links to the LWG issue. IMO the other question is sufficiently different to not close this as duplicate